# ASP.NET WEB API Forms Authentication Error

Tags: c#, .net, forms, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to create a `web api` with forms based authentication. I want to login from a client and retrieve data from there. When I log in, user gets authenticated and can retrieve data by giving `http request` direct into adressbar like `localhost:1393/api/Game`. But when i try to get it from client I am getting a `401 (Unauthorized error)`. I have enabled CORS in server side. This is the controller to handle data

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;

using System.Web.Security;
using Cheeky_backend.Models;
using System.Web.Http.WebHost;


namespace Cheeky_backend.Controllers
{
    public class Demo
    {
        public List<Teams> team { get; set; }
        public List<Hole> hole { get; set; }
    }

    [Authorize]
    public class GameController : ApiController
    {

        private Cheeky_backendContext db = new Cheeky_backendContext();



        // GET api/Game
        public IEnumerable<Hole> GetHoles()
        {
            return db.Holes.AsEnumerable();
        }


    }

}
```

This is the authenticating controler

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.Http;
using Cheeky_backend.Models;

namespace Cheeky_backend.Controllers
{
    public class UserController : ApiController
    {
        private Cheeky_backendContext db = new Cheeky_backendContext();

        // GET api/Default1


        // GET api/Default1/5


        // PUT api/Default1/5

        // POST api/Default1

        public HttpResponseMessage CreateUser(User user)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Users.Add(user);
                db.SaveChanges();

                HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, user);
           // response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = user.ID }));
                return response;
            }
            else
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
        }

        // DELETE api/Default1/5

        public HttpResponseMessage Login(User user)
        {
            var userfound = from user2 in db.Users
                            where user.username == user2.username && user.password == user2.password
                        select user2;

           if( userfound.Any())   
           {   
               FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.username, true);
               return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,user);
           }
          return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
       }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19835665/asp-net-webapi-basic-authentication-always-fails-as-401-unauthorized)

In your **Authentication Handler**

- Don't set the Principal on the `Thread.CurrentPrinicipal` any more.
- Use the `Principal` on the `HttpRequestContext`.

Take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19835665/asp-net-webapi-basic-authentication-always-fails-as-401-unauthorized)